# calculation of packing charges in java script

Tags: javascript

I have an tax invoice page for making invoice. I am using javascript for calculating the amount. I want to add courier charges in javascript. Can anybody help me?

Here is code

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var totalAmount = 0;
  $("[id^='price_']").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace("price_", '');
    var price = $('#price_' + id).val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity_' + id).val();
    if (!quantity) {
      quantity = 1;
    }
    var total = price * quantity;
    $('#total_' + id).val(parseFloat(total));
    totalAmount += total;
  });
  $('#subTotal').val(parseFloat(totalAmount));
  var taxRate = $("#taxRate").val();
  var subTotal = $('#subTotal').val();
  if (subTotal) {
    var taxAmount = subTotal * taxRate / 100;
    $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount);
    subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal) + parseFloat(taxAmount);
    $('#totalAftertax').val(subTotal);
    var amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
    var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();
    if (amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
      totalAftertax = totalAftertax - amountPaid;
      $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
    } else {
      $('#amountDue').val(subTotal);
    }
  }
```

Comment: put some html please, and what the error you faced in your code ?

Comment: i have to add packing charges in above code

Answer (score 0):

CSS is only for demo ( you can ignore it )

I added **packaging fees** & **shipping fees** with also FREE option each

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalAmount = 0;

  $("[id^='price_']").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("price_", '');

    var price = $('#price_' + id).val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity_' + id).val();

    if (!quantity) {
      quantity = 1;
    }

    var total = price * quantity;
    $('#total_' + id).val(parseFloat(total));

    totalAmount += total;
  });

  $('#subTotal').val(parseFloat(totalAmount));

  var taxRate = parseFloat($("#taxRate").val());
  var subTotal = parseFloat($('#subTotal').val());

  if (subTotal) {
    var taxAmount = subTotal * taxRate / 100;
    $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount);

    subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal) + parseFloat(taxAmount);
    $('#totalAftertax').val(subTotal);

    var amountPaid = $('#amountPaid').val();
    var totalAftertax = $('#totalAftertax').val();

    if (amountPaid && totalAftertax) {
      totalAftertax = totalAftertax - amountPaid;
      $('#amountDue').val(totalAftertax);
    } else {
      $('#amountDue').val(subTotal);
    }

    var amoutDue = parseFloat($('#amountDue').val());
    var shipping = parseFloat($('#shipping').val());
    var packaging = parseFloat($('#packaging').val());
    
    $('#amountDue').val(amoutDue + shipping + packaging);
  }
}
```

```css
[disabled],
[readonly] {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #888;
}

div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="price_1" type="number" value="5" />
  <input id="quantity_1" type="number" value="3" min="1" />
  <input id="total_1" type="number" value="15" readonly />
</div>

<div>
  <input id="price_3" type="number" value="15" />
  <input id="quantity_3" type="number" value="1" min="1" />
  <input id="total_3" type="number" value="15" readonly />
</div>

<div>
  <input id="price_8" type="number" value="20" />
  <input id="quantity_8" type="number" value="2" min="1" />
  <input id="total_8" type="number" value="40" readonly />
</div>

<div align="center">
  <button type="button" onclick="calculateTotal()">Update Cart</button>
</div>

<hr />



<div><label>Sub Total:</label>
  <input id="subTotal" type="number" value="0" readonly /></div>

<div><label>Tax Rate:</label>
  <input id="taxRate" type="number" value="15" readonly /></div>

<div><label>Tax Amount:</label>
  <input id="taxAmount" type="number" value="0" readonly /></div>

<div><label>Total After Tax:</label>
  <input id="totalAftertax" type="number" value="0" readonly /></div>

<div>
  <label>Shipping:</label>
  <select id="shipping" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="0">Regular FREE ( 12-15 days )</option>
    <option value="12.99">Express $12.99 ( 1-2 days )</option>
    <option value="9.99">UPS $9.99 ( 2-3 days )</option>
    <option value="6.99">DHL $6.99 ( 3-5 days )</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Packaging:</label>
  <select id="packaging" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option value="0">Regular FREE</option>
    <option value="2.99">Package 1 $2.99</option>
    <option value="4.99">Package 2 $4.99</option>
    <option value="7.99">Package 3 $7.99</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div><label>Amount Paid:</label> <input id="amountPaid" type="number" value="15" readonly /></div>

<div><label>Amount Due:</label> <input id="amountDue" type="number" value="0" readonly /></div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```